# iOS 9 and Xcode 7 Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios9, xcode7

i am new to ios 9 and xcode 7 when i am running my previous code on it i am getting this error:

ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Deployment Target** to iOS 6.0 or later. I attached the screenshot to help you to change it.

[image]